# To open any Libre Office File = "Start Recovery" and then "Finish"

Tags: libreoffice

I'm very new to Ubuntu and Libre Office. I transferred everything (my whole life!) from OSX yesterday!

Each time since this morning when I want to open a Libre Office file I'm faced with a dialog with the option to click first on "Start Recovery" and then on "Finish". This happens even if I have just opened and closed the file previously.

How can I fix this?

Comment: After the Start Recovery and Finish I can access my file....

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't deselect the auto recovery option. It will save your bacon at some point if you have a system freeze or power failure.

The prompt occurs when the auto recovery save contains newer information than your saved document. I also think the recovery files should delete themselves when libreoffice is shut down correctly.

In terms of your specific problem, I have seen this in the past when I save and then exit the application too quickly. I now save and wait 5 seconds before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

When `"Start Recovery"` popup comes just Select `"cancel"` option. It will clear pending recovery action.

Then navigate to:

> Tools -> Options -> Load/Save -> General > Save

And untick `"Save AutoRecovery information every 10 minutes"` option as shown in screenshot.

[image]